# jQueryMobile: Change font of text in a Listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple ListView:

```
<ol data-role='listview'>
   <li>Some Text</li>
</ol>
```

In this case, what's the CSS class that controls the font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
.ui-li-static{
   font-size:20px
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi, that doesn't make any difference. As there is no link, just text, the ui-link shouldn't be there?

Comment: Hi.. to change the size of the button in my app i used .ui-btn, i want to know what should i use to change the size of the textfields

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/aCmYc/1/

CSS

```
ol.someText li {
    font-size:30px;
}
ol.moreText li {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that setting .ui-li-static  will change it across all list views. You may want to add your own class to the ol to change it for only this one list item.